# Does moveToThread() rewrite direct connections to queued connections?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qobject

When moving an object from one thread to another, does `moveToThread()` automatically rewrite existing direct connections to queued connections?

Or in other words: Does it matter if automatic connections are established before or after a call to `moveToThread()`?

Unfortunately neither the documentation nor the WWW had an answer on this question.

Comment: I checked the wrong parts. I focused an moveToThread() and connect() and missed to check the connection type enumeration documentation because I surely did not expect the connection type to be checked on signal emission.

Comment: You can see it in the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/9754e5a03e4444a18ec7ca1525d196326ff4e038:src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L3516), if you're interested.

Comment: The connection type *must* be checked upon signal emission, since signals can be emitted, thread-safely, from *anywhere*. Even from foreign threads. It's a standard idiom to emit a signal from a callback from a C library, for example. The automatic connection type would be impossible without such an emission-time check. While a *slot* is associated with the thread context of the object, the signal isn't - it's merely associated with the connection list of the sending object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum): If the receiver lives in the thread that emits the signal, Qt::DirectConnection is used. Otherwise, Qt::QueuedConnection is used. **The connection type is determined *when the signal is emitted*.**

Comment: Hell, I missed that sentence! And I learned something very important... I always thought the actual connection type is determined when establishing the connection.

Answer (score 4):

No all direct connections stay direct and all queued connections stay queued.

However automatic connections will determine whether to queue or direct call at emit time. So it doesn't matter when automatic connections are set up relative to `moveToThread`.